# How can I save token for reuse in O365 python library?

Tags: python

I am reading and sending mails of my office 365 account using python O365 library to automate some regular tasks. Every time I want to use this API I have to do verification and get a fresh token and this token expires every 60 minutes. SO after some thorough research I found about a method called `FileSystemTokenBackend` however I'm still unable to save the token.  This is how I'm trying to save

```
token_backend = O365.FileSystemTokenBackend(token_path='G:/Newfolder', token_filename='my_token.txt')
```

Even after this command, no token is being saved.

Comment: same issue with me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/O365/#authentication), your token will be stored at the specified path **when you authenticate**.

After you have authenticated for the first time, the token will be read at the specified path. When you create and account with a token backend pointing to this path, this account will automatically be logged in.

```
token_backend = FileSystemTokenBackend(token_path='token_dir', token_filename='o365_token.txt')
account = Account(CREDENTIALS, token_backend=token_backend)
# If it's your first login, you will have to visit a website to authenticate and paste the redirected URL in the console. Then your token will be stored.
# If you already have a valid token stored, then account.is_authenticated is True.
if not account.is_authenticated:
    account.authenticate(scopes=['basic', 'message_all'])
```

Comment: This saves the token but that token lives for only for an hour or two. I think the person asking requires it to be useful for, lets say, a couple of days or months if not forever.

Comment: In my case the token lasts forever, this might be a setting to choose

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your needs. You could choose to store it in a file or in memory.

To store in a file:

```
import uuid


def write_token(token: str):
    with open('.secret_token', 'w') as file:
        file.write(token)


def get_token():
    with open('.secret_token', 'r') as file:
        return file.read()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_token = str(uuid.uuid4())
    print("Using token: {}".format(my_token))

    # store it
    write_token(my_token)

    # prove we stored the value
    print("Stored token: {}".format(get_token()))
```

To store in memory just replace the file with a `dict`

```
import uuid

_token_store = {}
_token_store_key = ":token:"

def write_token(token: str):
    _token_store[_token_store_key] = token


def get_token():
    return _token_store[_token_store_key]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_token = str(uuid.uuid4())
    print("Using token: {}".format(my_token))

    # store it
    write_token(my_token)

    # prove we stored the value
    print("Stored token: {}".format(get_token()))
```

Either way you should get output similar to this

```
$ python3 test.py
Using token: 79e9bb1b-0159-4065-9bee-d9fee383ae09
Stored token: 79e9bb1b-0159-4065-9bee-d9fee383ae09
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm not looking for randomly generated numbers to store as tokens. My requirement is different. I'm looking to store a token given by the O365 API. This token should be used in the Account class so that I don't need to login every time into my O365  account.

Comment: The token can be any string. I just used a random one to illustrate the point of saving any string

Comment: From Office365 docs the token is a base64 string so this method works.  "Access tokens issued by Azure AD are base 64 encoded JSON Web Tokens (JWT)" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-overview#what-is-an-access-token-and-how-do-i-use-it